# Javascript .load function error causing issues with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, load

I am making a basic PHP 'Game' for learning purposes.

For me, its all about learning PHP classes.

I have this part of javascript to keep loading 2 divs which contain 'game' information:

```
function bla() {
  var timeTillWinner = $(".time").html();
  if (timeTillWinner < '20') {
    $(".container").fadeOut();
    //alert(timeTillWinner);
  }
}

// function to reload the container
function pageUpdate(){
  $('body').load(document.URL +  '#playerList').load(document.URL + '.table-information');
  bla();
}
setInterval(pageUpdate, 10000);
```

The fadeOut() line is not working, yet the alert does fine. In my web console on firebug I see this everytime the pageUpdate() function is called:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/
SyntaxError: syntax error jquery.min.js:1
```

Any help on how to solve this error? I could go down the route of loading the div content with AJAX etc but just wanted something simple for now whilst I worked on the PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the code quoted is resulting in the error quoted. jQuery's `load` absolutely does not do a *synchronous* ajax request.

Comment: Unrelated: Your `load` calls are malformed. If your goal is to (at first) load the page and use its `#playerList` element as the only content, you need a space before the `#`: `.load(document.URL +  ' #playerList')`. Similarly the next `.load` with `.table-information`. But doing two `.load` calls like that one right after another doesn't make any sense, they'll occur chaotically and you'll only see the result of the second one that finishes.

Comment: Read more about .load function. You're not using it right at all